# How to implement custom links for a category?

Tags: magento2, category, toplinks, link

When a category is loaded, it uses links that lead to the category. How to add a field for the link in the category and if the field is filled in, as a result, the link by clicking on the category will go to the link that is indicated in the custom field?

Answer (score -1):

No need to do that. Just create url rewrite from category to some custom link when you need to do that. If do not need it anymore, just delete url rewrite. Url rewrites can be found in admin Marketing > Seo & Search > Url rewrites. This way you won't need any coding, no workarounds.